# How to train PyTorch remotely on another computer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, gpu

I am going to train a Neural Net using PyTorch. I will be working from a laptop without a dedicated GPU, but I have a stationary computer with a RTX 2070 at home. Is there any way to use the computing power of my stationary computer when working from my laptop?

The only possible solution I have now is programming everything remotely with something like Moonlight Game Streaming. Would perhaps work but introduces unnecessary elements.

Comment: *The only way* to do that involves moving your code to your computer at home. So yes, copy paste your entire code to your computer, using Moonlight Game Streaming, or whatever you wish. If you find any other way, it will do the same process; there is no alternative to copying your code

Comment: you can upload your code to a repo and clone it on the other side then push the trained model.

Comment: If you plan to mostly work at home (where your desktop PC stands), I would ask: Why not directly work on the stationary PC? Else, it could be possible to configure [SSH access to your stationary PC](https://dev.to/zduey/how-to-set-up-an-ssh-server-on-a-home-computer) and utilize this in you IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the home pc with laptop using SSH.

1. You have to config your router for granting ssh port forwarding. It's pretty easy and there are many resources for this.
2. Install SSH in stationary pc

> sudo apt-get install SSH

3. Install ssh client on your laptop

> ```
> sudo apt-get update 
>
> sudo apt-get upgrade 
>
> sudo apt-get install openssh-client
> ```

4. Then you can do `"ssh userName@serverName:/path/to/folder"` to login to stationary pc.

I normally use vs code for remote development. You can use remote explorer extension(`https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh`) in vscode to edit, run and code neural nets.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a SSH server on your stationary PC and connect your IDE from there.

[The instructions page for VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) also includes how to setup the host (your stationary PC), so it's worth checking out. You can also connect through SSH with PyCharm Professional (Add Interpreter -> On SSH).

If your laptop is on the same network as your host, you can just use your host's IP address to connect to it. (On Windows, run `ipconfig` in the terminal on your host PC. It should be "IPv4 Address", and should have the format 192.168.X.X). If you want to connect to it from another network, you'll need to set up port forwarding on your router.

Alternatively, you can push your code to github, connect to the host over SSH, pull it there, and then run the code. This works better if your model needs to run over several hours/days+. Just make sure that the path to your training data is set correctly.

Edit: Or you can use remote desktop applications like AnyDesk or Teamviewer or Parsec. [Moonlight is going to break sometime soon, anyway.](https://github.com/moonlight-stream/moonlight-docs/wiki/NVIDIA-GameStream-End-Of-Service-Announcement-FAQ)